# How to make a div into a Hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, html

I have problem in Visual Studio 2008 (ASP.net with C#).

I have div#apDiv13, now I want to make my div a hyperlink.

I set my div's background and now I want it to be a hyperlink on mouse over
or go to some address in web on-click.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

This is very bad idea but technically it's possible. What you need to do is display link as a block and set its size to 100% vertically and horizontally so it fills the container div.

Example (http://jsfiddle.net/snLwg/)

```
div {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

div a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you steve ! I need div to put a object like images and ... in it , so now I need to make div to hyperlink whenever I click on my div like image above

Comment: @HamedParvini you cannot make div into link, only with javascript. you can only make link to act like div. post some code and we will see what can be done.

Comment: Dear steve , this is my project , please download it , My div is in Index.aspx file , please check the Sin in div , I want it to make hyperlink .         http://uplod.ir/c90tgwhj29a1/YalaYal.rar.htm

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
    <div>Contents of your div</div>
</a>
```

Comment: That is not valid markup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct